# C++17 multiplying a list using reduce in conjunction with multiplies doesn't work

Tags: c++, c++17

I'd like to multiply the elements of a float list using `reduce` in conjunction with `multiplies`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  vector<float>series{2, 1.91421, 2.06538, 2.25, 2.43607}; 
  float result = reduce(series.begin(), series.end(), 1, multiplies<float>() );
  cout << "result: " << result << endl; // it's 29
  // it must have been 43.340291222788287 
}
```

How to do it correctly?
Please note that, I'd like to do it using specifically `reduce` in conjuction with the `multiplies`, not any other function such as `transform_reduce` or any other method, as much as possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that the interface of [`reduce()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reduce) is:

```cpp
template<class InputIt, class T, class BinaryOp>
T reduce(InputIt first, InputIt last, T init, BinaryOp binary_op);
```

Notably, it deduces the type from the initial value and returns that type. You're passing in `1`, which is an `int`. So this returns `int` and the internal accumulator is an `int`. That's... not going to work well for obvious reasons (doesn't matter that you're using `multiplies<float>`, the result gets stored in an `int` anyway).

You want:

```
float result = reduce(series.begin(), series.end(), 1.0f, multiplies<float>() );
```

You don't even really need to specify the type on `multiplies`, `multiplies{}` works fine.